# Marginal distribution of a Poisson rate

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, inference, poisson-distribution

I have a random sample of Yi~Poisson(θ) with i=1,..,n. Where I assume a gamma(a,b) prior for θ. Where I'm able to find the marginal distribution of Y to be a NegativeBionomial(a,p) where p=(1/(1+b),

[image]

However, I want to expand this now to find the marginal distribution of a Poisson with rate θ, and what I mean by that is Yi is Poisson(ui=Ei*θ). I've tried using the same idea as before however I'm not sure how to handle the Ei*θ now and whether or not it still provides a Negative Binomial as the marginal distribution.

Comment: I didn't get your question, is `E` expectation operator?

Comment: Ei in this case is just the exposure.